# get point in polynomial at certain length

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have a polynomial $y = f(x)$ of order $3/4/5$. I have start and end $x$ values and also the coefficients of the polynomial.

The polynomial is supposed to represent a path on a road.

Now, I would like to get the $y, x$ values at a certain length along the polynomial path. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you know how to use calculus to find the [arc length](https://brilliant.org/wiki/arc-length/)?

Comment: Yes. I do understand how to get the arc length (using numerical integration methods). With this approach I can keep integrating till I reach the required length to get my x and then corresponding y.

Is there anything better/ faster?